# MPIexec.exe Access denide

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

I have installed microsoft compute cluster and MPI.net, now i have trouble to run program using mpiexec.exe on cluster. When i try to run it on console i get message: "Access Denied", and pop up: "mpiexec.exe is not valid win32 application".

I tried google it, but found nothing. Pls help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually that means that you're attempting to run an x64 binary on an x86 platform. Is this likely what is happening?

Comment: I still dont know what happened, but i reinstalled everything and it worked..:)